# Error in 1:nrow(Boston_data$value) : argument of length 0 in R. Why?

Tags: r, loops

I have been trying to go through every row of the dataframe column named value and predict value using a model in order to solve the following task: Create a new variable displaying the predicted value by the model from 3) and calculate its average. Compare this with the average of the actual value variable.

```
pa <- 1

  for (pa in 1:nrow(Boston_data$value)){
    valuee <- predict(model1, pa)
  }
```

However, I received an output

```
Error in 1:nrow(Boston_data$value) : argument of length 0
```

Comment: Learn to do some debugging. It's good for you. What do you get from `nrow(Boston_data$value)`

Comment: @Dason I get NULL

Comment: I'm guessing that isn't what you expected.   Sounds like a good place to start investigations.

Comment: @Dason But there are values in dataframe. What to do?

Comment: Right. Figure out why *nrow* when applied to Boston_data$value gives NULL.  One might expect it would tell you how many rows that object has.  Does that actually have rows? Is it a dataframe?

Comment: It is a dataframe

Comment: No it isn't.  Really investigate.  Boston_data might be a dataframe. But we're talking about Boston_data$value

Comment: It is a name of a column in the dataframe

Comment: Ok. I'm going to let you work this out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 1:length(Boston_data$value) instead of nrow, since Boston_data$value will return a vector, not dataframe.